# Wordpress post visualization on homepage

Tags: php, wordpress

i am not able to display the custom fields in a wordpress home page.
This is the code (fully working except for the part that show the custom field)

```
<?php 
  $thumbnails = get_posts('numberposts=3&cat=3');
  foreach ($thumbnails as $thumbnail) {
    if ( has_post_thumbnail($thumbnail->ID)) {
        echo '<div class="contest-home"><a href="' . get_permalink( $thumbnail->ID ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $thumbnail->post_title ) . '">';
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail($thumbnail->ID, 'medium',  array('class'=> "blur") );
        echo '</a>';
    echo '<h2><center>' . esc_attr( $thumbnail->post_title ) . '</center></h2>';
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "RiassuntoHome", true);
    echo '<p><b>Giorni restanti:</b> 30 giorni';
    echo '<br><b>Premio:</b> 10.000 euro';
    echo '</p><center><a class="st-btn slarge st-btn-green st-btn-slarge" href="' . get_permalink( $thumbnail->ID ) . '">Invia la Tua Idea</a></center></div>';
    }
  }
?>
<?php echo '<div class="clearfix"></div></div>' ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object is `$thumbnail`, not `$post`:

```
echo get_post_meta($thumbnail->ID, "RiassuntoHome", true);
```